# bridge not created automatically

Tags: gentoo, bridge

I've set up a bridge that works perfectly but it doesn't get created when booting up.

I've searched everywhere and ensured to follow [Gentoo's bridging guide](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Network_bridge) to the letter to no avail.

My network configuration is fine and the bridge starts properly after manually doing:

```
brctl addbr br0
brctl addif br0 enp1s0
```

A simple `service net.br0 start` gets everything going after that.

Doing a `service net.br0 restart` afterwards causes the same problem since it destroys the bridge but doesn't recreate it.

Note that `net.br0` is indeed called when booting up but fails because the bridge does not exist.

Can anyone tell me how to get the bridge created automatically when booting up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the bridge members got populated automatically by other scripts, I had not included them in `/etc/conf.d/net`, which is why the system did not create it.

Adding `bridge_br0="enp1s0"` to `/etc/conf.d/net` solved the issue.